# Orwell: "A glimmer [is] one who watches vacant motor-cars." What does this mean?

Tags: british-english, slang, history, twentieth-century-english

Title is a quote from Orwell's *Down and Out in Paris and London*. In this section he goes through a bunch of London slang terms and what they mean, but I don't understand his definition. What does it mean to watch vacant motor-cars? The only thing I can think of is someone who you pay when you park who makes sure nobody steals your car when it's gone. But how does that work? What assurance does the driver have that the person watching won't just leave or steal the car themselves?

Comment: There seems nothing beyond 'Glimmer: one who watches vacant motor cars' available on the internet. I assume it does indeed refer to 'someone who you pay when you park your car to "make sure nobody steals it when **you**'ve  gone" '. // Your final question is not about English, but when my father used to pay kids in a certain part of Manchester for this service, it was tacitly assumed that they'd be at the match before us, but would not damage the car.

Comment: Paying someone (unofficial) to park and look after your car was common when I lived in Sicily. The confidence came from the fact that this was how they made their living. If they didn't provide a reliable service, they would be out of work. (And there may have been "others" behind the scenes who organised this semi-legal activity.)

Answer (score 4):

Orwell attempts the etymology of his slang, saying of *glimmer*

> '**Glimmer**' (with the verb 'to glim') may have something to do with the
>   old word 'glim', meaning a light, or another old word 'glim', meaning
>   a glimpse;

*Down and Out* was published in 1933, a memoir of his time spent destitute in London in 1927 and Paris in 1928. He seems to have missed the slang word *glimmers* (also *glims*) meaning eyes, words current in London slang during the 1920s according to Partridge's *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*.

So a **glimmer** is someone who used his glimmers to (in modern parlance) keep his eye on something, in this case your car when you leave it somewhere dicey. Presumably this works in the usual way: you pay half up front and the other half when you retrieve your car undamaged. You have no assurance that the glimmer won't be satisfied with half or that he's not working for a chop shop.

Answer (score 3):

> **glimming** n. [glim v. (2); note London cab-driver jargon, glim, to look for a cab] (UK Und.)

watching out for cabs etc. for wealthy people, in return for a tip. ...

http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199829941.001.0001/acref-9780199829941-e-20048

Answer (score 1):

However, in chapter XXXIII of Down and Out in London and Paris, Paddy earns a few extra shillings through glimming, which is referred to as a precarious job because it is illegal. Watching a car to ensure it isn’t stolen surely isn’t illegal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).